# How to reindex csv data efficiently?

Tags: python, pandas, bigdata

I have a file that I downloaded of tick data from the internet. It looks like this. The file is relatively "large"

```
time,bid,bid_depth,bid_depth_total,offer,offer_depth,offer_depth_total
20150423T014501,81.79,400,400,81.89,100,100
20150423T100001,81.,100,100,84.36,100,100
20150423T100017,81.,100,100,83.52,500,500
20150423T115258,81.01,500,500,83.52,500,500
...
```

I then want to reindex the data so that I can access it through time type query:

```
from pylab import *
from pandas import *
import pandas.io.date_converters as conv

XLE = read_csv('XLE.csv') # Chunking seems somewhat kludy XLE = pd.read_csv('XLE.csv', chunksize=4)
#preferred something like XLE = pd.read_csv('XLE.csv', index_col=0, parse_dates=True) but can't handle this time format?

XLE = XLE.drop_duplicates(cols='time')

for i in XLE.index :
    XLE [ 'time' ][ i ]= datetime.strptime ( XLE [ 'time' ][ i], '%Y%m%dT%H%M%S')
XLE.index = XLE [ ' time ' ]; del XLE [ 'time']

print XLE[['bid','offer']].ix[1000:1015].to_string() # this is the goal, to be able to manipulate the data through a time index.
```

My questions are:

1. When I run this in the shell, it takes quite a bit of time even for one file. I am certain I must be doing something wrong in my approach, as the goal is to read many files and merge them into a pandas DataFrame/Timeseries
2. Pandas appears to be an in memory type of approach. What do people do when the file(s) are truly big and can't all fit in memory? Is there a pandas interface that hides from pandas where the data actually resides so that the file is loaded and unloaded as needed from disk as computation progresses?
3. It seems more logical to apply the filter to the time column as it is being read in then to operate on it later. Is there a way to do this by telling the read function what function to call as it reads the column, *before* storing the object in memory?

Comment: You need to explicitly define big/large here -- later you imply not fitting in memory, but be explicit from the start about that.  I'd also consider changing the title as your question is much more specific then the title would suggest (you might get downvoted on the title alone).  Also, best practice is not to import as *.  For pandas, pd is standard.

Comment: I changed the title. Using the linux wc command,  17745  17745 825340 XLE.csv and yet the reindexing takes a long time and it crashes if I do it on too many files. I have 8 GB or RAM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a little too lazy too figure out exactly what's going on here, but this is going to be super slow because you're explicitly looping rather than using pandas built in vectorized methods.  (Basically avoid 'for' when using pandas, if possible, and it's usually possible.)

```
for i in XLE.index :
    XLE [ 'time' ][ i ]= datetime.strptime ( XLE [ 'time' ][ i], '%Y%m%dT%H%M%S')
XLE.index = XLE [ ' time ' ]; del XLE [ 'time']
```

You can convert time to a pandas datetime pretty easily with this:

```
XLE['time'] = pd.to_datetime(XLE.time)
```

I'm not sure why `parse_dates` with `read_csv` didn't work for you there but you can also use `date_parser` and specify the specific format that way.

Then if you want to make it the index:

```
XLE = XLE.set_index('time')
```

That should get you started.  Once 'time' is a pandas datetime you can do all sorts of things (just see the docs).  These things ought to be pretty fast if things fit in memory.  If not, there are a number of answers at SO that can help you with that, although buying more memory is always the simplest solution, if feasible.